# How do you extract a point spread function from a fits image?

Tags: python, fits

I'm new to python coding and I have a .fits image of a star and I want to extract the PSF from it. How would i go about doing this?

After that how would I fit a Gaussian curve to it?

Answer (score 6):

What exactly do you mean with "extracting the PSF from it"? Do you want find its position? Do you want to cut out a box around it? What is it that you in the end want to do with it?

Assuming that you just have an image `image.fits` with a PSF in it, you can use `astropy.modeling` to fit a 2D Gaussian to your PSF, after figuring out where its center in the provided image is.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
from astropy.io import fits

# Load the data and find center of PSF
image = fits.getdata('path/image.fits')
cents = np.where(image == np.max(image))
xc = int(cents[1])
yc = int(cents[0])

# Cut out smaller box around PSF
bb = 30
box = image[yc-bb:yc+bb,xc-bb:xc+bb]
yp, xp = box.shape

# Generate grid of same size like box to put the fit on
y, x, = np.mgrid[:yp, :xp]
# Declare what function you want to fit to your data
f_init = models.Gaussian2D()
# Declare what fitting function you want to use
fit_f = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()

# Fit the model to your data (box)
f = fit_f(f_init, x, y, box)

# Plot the data with the best-fit model
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2.5))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(box)
plt.title("Data")
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(f(x, y))
plt.title("Model")
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(box - f(x, y))
plt.title("Residual")
plt.show()
```

[Image: 2D Gaussian fit to PSF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kgd7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the functions available in either [astropy](https://www.astropy.org/) or [photoutils](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I've used the [airy convolution](http://docs.astropy.org/en/older-docs-archive/v0.3/convolution/kernels.html) in astropy to model a PSF, but from your question, I think the photoutils [PSF](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/psf.html) or [ePSF](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/epsf.html) page are what you are looking for.